# API does not support sessions. how can I use the session in API?

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel eCommerce API. API does not support sessions. how can I develop cart functionality without storing cart items in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can't use sessions in api because larval won't initiate sessions in case of api. look at **[kernel.php.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L33)**

You can add middleware "`web`" to your route or add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`, to middleware api anyway. But try to avoid it (personal opinion).